# How to know the test case failure reason in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I'm running the unit tests and getting the result `Test failed`
Here is the exception I'm getting:

```
Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 5 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "SIGN-UP step1 with valid email & pw succeeds".
```

How can I define the failure reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to look at the code for the lest and the code that is being tested but it looks like the asynchronous "sign up" function didn't complete within 5 seconds.

Comment: The reason is printed there. The asynchronous XCTestExpectation  test "SIGN-UP step1 with valid email & pw succeeds" didn’t `fulfill` after 5 seconds of waiting. Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Your test is clearly using an expectation, with a 5 second timeout. Your asynchronous call didn't fulfill the expectation within 5 seconds (either because it was too slow or because you have a path of execution where you fail fulfill the expectation).

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your question to include the test in question.